# c# Being able to use local variables in other methods

Tags: c#

Ive got this code and its all fine but there is a local variable that i would like to use in a button method and was wondering if anyone knew how to turn a local variable into a global one.Specifically the left and right local string variables.

````
            {
                StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName);



                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = inputFile.ReadLine(); 
                    var splittedLine = line.Split(','); 
                    var left = splittedLine[0]; 
                    var right = splittedLine[1]; 

                    lefts.Add(left); 
                    rights.Add(right); 

                    listBox1.Items.Add(" ID   " + left + " Marks  " + right); 
                } ```
````

Comment: Where are lefts and rights defined? You could declare them outside the method in the class, or modify the method above to return a reference to them using the out keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

Comment: wdym there definded as var left and var right and i would like to use those two local variables outside of this method

Answer (score 0):

Declare it outside of your function.

```
int left = 0;
```

And assign to it inside your function.

```
left = 123;
```

Then you can use it anywhere.

Comment: Yes i thought this aswell but it doesnt work gives errors saying it cannot convert string to int

Comment: @HashimAbdi well of course you need to use the correct datatype. So use string instead of int to declare.

Answer (score 0):

Do a variable outside of the function called

```
string left = string.empty;
```

or use a property if it's part of a class

```
string left {get;set;}
```

Then you can assign it within that class.

Please look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/ to get a better understanding of variable scope.